# Tools to prove if a set is compact

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know the definition of a compact set: A set is called compact if it is closed and bounded. I am an engineer not a mathematician:) Are there tools/recipes how to prove if a set is closed and bounded? 
An easy example: $S=\{(x,y): x>0, y>0\}$

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Your definition is only true for finite dimension. (See e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem#Generalizations).)

Comment: Ok thank you - I think for "the start" I am fine with finite dimensions

Comment: I think topology is also an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Euclidean space, then the Heine Borel theorem states that any subset of Euclidean space which is closed and bounded is compact. In this case, your set is not closed as I can define a sequence that converges to $(0,0)$ but this is not in your set.

Some equivalent conditions for compactness are being:

1. Sequentially compact- every sequence has a convergent subsequence
2. Covering compact- every open covering reduces to a finite subcovering
3. Being closed an totally bounded
4. Being complete and totally bounded

Comment: It is important to remark that those are equivalent conditions for metric spaces, but not in general.

Comment: Hey - thank you very much for your reply! What does that mean (and how do you do that): I can define a sequence that converges to (0,0). Is this the general approach, to define sequences? Sorry - as I said - I am not a mathematician.

Comment: It depends on the context, if defining sequences is easier then yes that's the typical approach. But you can let $(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ be a sequence and as $n$ goes to infinity we can see this goes to $(0,0)$.  Since $(0,0)$, is not in your set but is the limit of ansequence in your set it is not closed, and therefore not compact.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told that finite dimensions are usually all people in non-math fields need for practice, so let's assume we're in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some positive integer $n$, and your characterization of compactness works: $S$ is compact if and only if $S$ is closed and bounded.

$S$ is a bounded set if and only if it is contained in a ball of finite radius. If we let $S=\{(x,y):x>0,y>0\}$ as in your example, we notice that if we pick some arbitrary point in $S$ and take a ball of finite radius around it, there is always a point in $S$ outside of the ball (ex: $B_{100}((100,100))$ doesn't contain $(1000000, 1000000)$ which is a point in $S$).

To check if $S$ is closed, we can check if 1) $S^c$ is open, or 2) for every sequence $\{s_n\}\subset S$ that converges to a point $s\in \mathbb{R}^n$, see if $s\in S$ (i.e. $S$ contains all of its limit points). Let's see how these methods work with your example $S$:

1) $S^c=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x\le 0, y\le 0\}$. $S^c$ is open if and only if for every $s\in S$, there exists an open ball around $s$ with radius $r>0$ such that $B_r(s)\subset S^c$. But notice that there is no ball around $(0,0)$ that is contained in $S^c$, since $B_r((0,0))$ contains the point $(r/2,r/2)$ and $S^c$ does not contain any points with positive coordiantes.

2) Let $s_n=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ and observe that since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=(0,0)$. $S$ does not contain $(0,0)$ since it only contains points that have strictly positive coordinates. So $S$ is not closed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer! Can I say: If a set has strict inequalities, then it can’t be closed?  I.e. the above set would be closed if greater or equal than 0 (or any number)? But that set would not be bounded right? And regarding 2) Every "item" of the sequence is inside the set, except the limit point?

Comment: To your last question, yes. We only need to check sequences in which every term of the sequence is inside the set. 

To your first question, seems that way but I'm not sure. Seems you could always construct a sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ approaching the strict bound.

No problem!